# Neural network testing error range

Tags: java, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I'm implementing a neural network in Java, which only uses fully connected layers.

I'm training the net with a simple sine function, where `x` (in [0, 1]) is given as an input, and
`(1 + Math.sin(x * 2 * Math.PI))/2` as an output.

As shown on the image, the error looks to be decreasing to around 10% which, as far as I know, isn't too bad for such a network. The plot shows the *mean values* for each 200 iterations or so.

When testing specific values, I experience a huge range of error. They go from say 0.1% to thousands of percents. Though on average they look to be around the value given by the training curve, the network truly fails around every ten tests.

My question is: is it "normal" for the net to have such an unstable behaviour? Is it common for such a problem to get this range of errors, even though they don't seem to come up "so" often? I thought the response would be "smoother", which is why I'm asking.

Any feedback appreciated, thanks a lot!

[Training error curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON1Nm.png)

Edit: 
1) I get the error percentage in the testing phase with:
`Math.abs((networkOutput-expectedOutput)/expectedOutput)*100`. I only use the expectedOutput and not this error percentage for training.

2) About the training: in short, I run this loop:

```
double input = Math.random();
double output = trainingFunction(input);
net.backPropagate(input, output);
```

with trainingFunction returning the normalized sine function seen above,  backPropagate first executing the network and then using the gradient descent method and the derivative of the sigmoid to compute the weights' delta.

3) The topology is 1 input neuron -> 20 hidden neurons -> 1 output neuron. I also notice the same kind of results when using more hidden layers.

Comment: What do you mean by "training with a simple sine function"? Is this your Input/Output? I hope this is not your activation function since it would be better to use a logistic function.

Comment: Yes, it's the input/output. The activation function is a sigmoid.

Comment: thousands of percent?? that sounds unnatural on first thought - why would the error be more than 100% something is wrong with your functions - you need to get the training error down to 0.001

Comment: Could you give us more details about how do you train your network, what is a topology of it and clarify what sort of error function you use? Notice that error is not measured in percents by it is a real number. What do you mean by error in specific values? How do you measure it in percents?

Comment: I edited the question and added a few elements. At least now I know this not a normal behaviour, I'll review my implementation. Thank you already!

Comment: @gpasch "you need to get the training error down to 0.001." I would be careful with this kind of statements. In the given scenario, it might be possible. In real-world applications, however, it is undesirable to "train until the error is minimal" since the system tends to overfit and this is neither desirable nor constructive.

Comment: @Turing85 we need to joggle the user in the right direction we are not running the business schooll of computing

Comment: Have you tried using Deeplearning4j for this? 
http://deeplearning4j.org/

Comment: @gpasch So why not under 0.00001 then. Your advice is not helpful, especially that you are talking about training error, not e.g. validation error.